MAUI and Firebase Build Issues in .NET 8 MAUI project
I am currently in the process of converting my .NET MAUI project from .NET 6 to .NET 8. However, I am encountering build issues. When I try to build or rebuild my project, I receive Firebase-related errors, as shown in this screenshot:
Build Error
Interestingly, everything was working perfectly in the previous version. I am unsure why this issue has arisen.
I am using the Plugin.Firebase package by Tobias Buchholz. Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I have tried deleting bin and obj folders and then rebuilding the project, nothing works as of now and the error still persists.
Also made changes in registry editor for allowing longpath for files[ have set it to 1], even after this issue persists.
